# virtual function is not resolving to most derived class method

Tags: c++, debugging, object, polymorphism

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ShapeTwoD
 { 
   public:
      virtual int get_x(int);




   protected:
    int x;
 };


class Square:public ShapeTwoD
{    
    public:
      void set_x(int,int);

      int get_x(int);





       private:
        int x_coordinate[3];
        int y_coordinate[3];


};

int main()
 {
    Square* s = new Square;

s->set_x(0,20);

cout<<s->get_x(0)
    <<endl;




    ShapeTwoD shape[100];

    shape[0] = *s;

cout<<shape->get_x(0); //outputs 100 , it doesn't resolve to 
                           //  most derived function and output 20 also


 }

void Square::set_x(int verticenum,int value)
{
  x_coordinate[verticenum] = value;

}


int Square::get_x(int verticenum)
{
  return this->x_coordinate[verticenum];

}

 int ShapeTwoD::get_x(int verticenum)
 {
   return 100;

 }
```

shape[0] has been initialised to Square . When i call shape->get_x , i cant understand 
why shape->get_x does not resolve to the most derived class instead it resolves to the base
class method of shape->get_x . I have already made the get_x method virtual in my base class .

Can someone explain to me why and how to resolve this issue??

Comment: You've got an array of `ShapeTwoD`'s, not an array of `Square`s. Look up "object slicing".

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the slicing problem in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In these lines:

```
ShapeTwoD shape[100];
shape[0] = *s;
```

you have "slicing". Your `shape` array contains `ShapeTwoD`s and you assign from `*s` to the first `ShapeTwoD`. This does not change the type of `shape[0]`, so it is *not* an object of type `Square`. Polymorphism could only work when you use pointers:

```
ShapeTwoD* shape[100]; // now you have 100 (uninitialized) pointers
shape[0] = s;

cout << shape[0]->get_x(0);
```

Comment: Thanks , appreciate your help